# How do I create an embedded object in Swagger YAML?

Tags: swagger, hal, swagger-editor

I want to add a HAL resource linking to a definition,

```
definitions
  HalItemResponse:
    name:
      type: string
```

What to add

```
"_links": {
"self": string,
"filter": string
}
```

How?

Answer (score 3):

Where ever you want to use the definition, typically in a request or response you'd reference it like so.

JSON

```
{
    halitem: { $ref: '#/defintions/HalItemResponse' }
}
```

YAML

```
halitem:
    $ref: '#/definitions/HalItemResponse'
```

Very similar to setting the type but instead pointing to the definition schema.